Does the unidirection TVS diode like SMAJ15A be used on DC lines to protect the IC or Converters from negative Peak, clamp down to -0.6V?
Most of the DC- DC converters have absolute maximum down to -0.6. If bidirectional TVS diode is used then negative peak cannot be clamped near to -0.6v, in this is the case can we use the unidirectional TVS diode?. For example the SMAJ15A, has instantaneous forward voltage around 3.3 to 5.0V, but where as SMAJ15CA is having a clamping voltage 19V.

Below image is from an application note mentioning the use of the Unidirectional TVS diodes in the Dc Power lines and Digital Signals
https://www.lentark.com/download.php?filename=TVS_Diodes_Application_Note_2.pdf

But if we check on forums online there is divide between usage of uni-directional and Bi-Directional almost every where.

I think you'll find better information in this graph that is on page 4 of the data sheet but note that the two numbers in the table refer to single and stacked dies: -

Then it boils down to the maximum reverse input voltage specification for the converter versus, how much forward voltage the TVS diode produces at the worst case overload current. Note that the graph is showing typical values.
However, if you have a decent amount of input capacitance on the converter, this can soak up a lot of energy before the voltage rises higher than 0.6 volts so, I recommend that you use a simulator and perform some simulations for the various surge currents that you might expect to see.
Or, if you can, power the converter through a diode rectifier so that reverse voltages are virtually eliminated at any serious energy level.
